How do you build a Coherent Elastic Neutrino-Nucleus Scattering (CEvNS) detector?
*Milkjug-sized neutrino detector (the COHERENT neutrino detector):

https://news.uchicago.edu/story/worlds-smallest-neutrino-detector-observes-elusive-interactions-particles#:~:text=The%204%2Dinch%2Dby%2D,of%20tons%20of%20detector%20material
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpzzjccziyY&t=1s

This question is similar to: Is a DIY neutrino detector feasible?. The difference between my question, and the old one is that the question is from over 8 years ago. Naturally, some of the answers are outdated and the links to materials they provide are all expired. Additionally, we now have neutrino detectors the size of milk jugs, so now a DIY Neutrino Detector is much more feasible than the answers in the older question indicated. Given this, I ask my questions because I want to know how feasible it is today, and what is required to make it.
*If you see this question and have any level of knowledge on the question for you to be able to edit the questions to make them more specific, by all means please feel free to do so. I also want to mention that I am looking for something more along the lines of general advice rather than specifically engineering questions. Especially since the questions I am asking are mostly only going to be able to be answered by a physicist, rather than an engineer.
How does the COHERENT neutrino detector, detect neutrinos and CEvNS? And why does it work despite its incredibly small size?
Considering that we now have neutrino detectors the size of milk jugs (COHERENT), how might one make their own ('DIY') neutrino detector?
*The following questions serve as order of magnitude requests to give me an idea of how feasible this project that I am very passionate about is. It gives me an idea of how much money I am going to need to request, raise, and apply for grants for.
What might you need if you had a large budget to make it? And what would you need if you had a limited budget?
Are any of the supplies you might need to build your own neutrino detector be cheaper if you made them yourself?

You should really link all cited information so people don't have to dig around and search what you're talking about. I'm familiar with small neutrino detectors (still likely prohibitively expensive to the layperson). But you should include what detectors you're talking about.

I disagree with the engineering-like closure of this question. I think that questions about the construction and operation of equipment whose main or only purpose is physics research, such as a neutrino detector, are more about physics than they are about engineering. When I was building particle detectors, I gave talks about their nitty-gritties at physics conferences, not at engineering conferences.  I'm reopening this question using my moderator superpower. I'm happy to have a discussion about the topic on [meta] if the community disagrees, and I won't override other close votes.

@rob it is done

You're asking a wide variety of questions here. Please narrow this down to a more specific question or break it up into 2-3 question posts.

I had to look up what "CEvNS" meant (since it's not defined in the post), then I got annoyed when I found out that the v is actually a $\nu$ but is stylized as a "v" to make the abbreviation pronounced "sevens" (cf. here) instead of "sense". Physicists should be banned from naming things.

@KyleKanos To be fair, it is in the title

Considerations for improvement: (a) Don't make the question look like a revision history. Make the question ask what you want it to ask, without apology. (b) Your title suggests that you're interested in neutrinos interacting coherently with an entire nucleus (as in COHERENT), as opposed to neutrinos interacting with one nucleon or one electron in an atom (as in miniTimeCube). But your text suggests that you just want to build a little detector for whichever interaction. Those are fairly different questions.

@rob I just edited it to try and make this a smoother and more coherent read.

@BioPhysicist I can't read or write

@rob How about now?

@Justyn As I wrote above last week, I'm not going to unilaterally re-open the question a second time. It's current in our reopen queue whether other community members will evaluate it. See the [help] for details about how closing and reopening work around here.

I would love to vote to reopen. At the moment it still feels too broad with all of the questions, and the meta-text makes the post harder to parse as well.

I would instantly vote to reopen if you simply deleted everything after "How does the COHERENT neutrino detector, detect neutrinos and CEvNS? And why does it work despite its incredibly small size?". (Also please delete the added meta text.)  You could then ask additional separate questions referencing this one, e.g.  "What would be the most inexpensive way to detect neutrinos?" and "How small could a neutrino detector be?".  For these latter questions, you'd need to specify the neutrino source, energies and flux,  and whether the cost and size of the neutrino source should be included.

I'm glad the question is reopened. I'll post an answer in the next couple of days.

@rob  :)))))))

@Justyn Life is complicated. I have moved house, which I knew about at the end of July, and I have quit my non-physics job and returned to teaching full time, which I had not anticipated. I have two or three Physics posts in my queue to respond to "soon," but I don't know what "soon" might be.
